# Column output have query in it how can i execute it with current resultset in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

My column contains a query (SQL text), how can I execute that with current resultset in SQL Server?

[image: Question given below in image]

Comment: Hint:  `exec sp_executesql`.

Comment: could you fit this in dynamic sql TO GET REQUIRED OUTPUT?

   SELECT DISTINCT 
      ,[job]
      ,[business_event] 
    FROM @acc_eba_sheme

Comment: Beware of [2nd order SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection)...